# Laravel route 404 page

Tags: laravel, nginx, web

I have nginx on my ubuntu server and I added a new controller to my laravel project and a route to it in routes/api. But when I try to follow this route, I get a 404 error. Here my code.

```
class TelegramController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['SendMessage']]);
    }
    public function SendMessage(Request $request)
    {
        $formData = $request->all();

        $messageText = "Name: " . $formData['name'] . "; Phone: " . $formData['number'];
        $encodedMessage = urlencode($messageText);
        $botToken = "token";
        $chatsId[] = "chatid";
        $chatsId[]  = "chatid";
        foreach ($chatsId as $value)
        {
            $telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $botToken . "/sendMessage?chat_id=" . $value . "&text=" . $encodedMessage;
            file_get_contents($telegramUrl);
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => 'successfully']);

    }
}
```

```
Route::post('telegram.create',[TelegramController::class,'SendMessage']);
```

It is also worth noting that such an error is only on the server, everything is fine on the local.
error 404 on the page *my domain*/api/telegram.create worth noting that everything is in order with the rest of the routes

i tried to enter php artisan route:clear on the server and yes, indeed now the route appeared in php artisan route:list but the 404 error is still there

Comment: Can you please show the nginx configuration?